# Compute the length of an intersection curve

Tags: curves, arc-length

I am asked too calculate the exact length of the intersection curve of the two equations
$$ 
x^2 = 2 y \\
3z = xy \\
$$

From the point `(0,0,0)` to the point `(6,18,36)`.

I don't know if I am doing the right thing, but I am starting to isolate $x$ from the first equation and insert it in the second equation to find the equation of the intersection curve.

I find

$$
z = \frac{x^3}{6}
$$

The way to compute it is probably to find transform the equation of the intersection into a parametric equation using a new variable `t` for example. From there, I know how to compute the length, but I will have problem of setting the interval of the integral expressed as the `t` variable.

Can someone give me a clue on how to passed from an equation of this form to a parametric equation and give me a hint on how to set the interval?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have already found you can use $t=x$ as a parameter:

$$x=t,\ y=t^2/2,\ z=t^3/6,$$

so the interval becomes $[0,6].$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that in general, it is easy to set $x$ as equal to $t$ for parametrisation or there can be other methods that comes out often?